# How to access attributes of a dendrogram in R

Tags: r, attributes, dendrogram, dendextend

From a dendrogram which i created with

```
hc<-hclust(kk)
hcd<-as.dendrogram(hc)
```

i picked a subbranch

```
k=hcd[[2]][[2]][[2]][[2]][[2]][[2]][[2]][1]
```

When i simply have k displayed, this gives:

```
> k
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 243
attr(,"label")
[1] "NAfrica_002"
attr(,"members")
[1] 1
attr(,"height")
[1] 0
attr(,"leaf")
[1] TRUE

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 257
attr(,"label")
[1] "NAfrica_016"
attr(,"members")
[1] 1
attr(,"height")
[1] 0
attr(,"leaf")
[1] TRUE

attr(,"members")
[1] 2
attr(,"midpoint")
[1] 0.5
attr(,"height")
[1] 37
```

How can i access, for example, the "midpoint" attribute, or the second of the "label" attributes?

(I hope i use the correct terminology here)

I have tried things like

```
k$midpoint
attr(k,"midpoint")
```

but both returned 'NULL'.

Sorry for question number 2: how could i add a "label" attribute after the attribute "midpoint"?

Comment: If you had  used `k=hcd[[2]][[2]][[2]][[2]][[2]][[2]][[2]][[1]]`, you would have gotten just the contents rather than having them packaged in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `k` is still buried one layer too deep. The attributes have been set on the first element of the list `k`.

```
 attributes(k[[1]]) # Display attributes
 attributes(k[[1]])$label # Access attributes
 attributes(k[[1]])$label <- 'new' # Change attribute
```

Alternatively, you can use `attr`:

```
attr(k[[1]],'label') # Display attribute
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change parameters manually as in the previous answer. The problem with this is that it is not efficient to do manually when you want to do it many times. Also, while it is easy to change parameters - that change may not be reflected in any other function, since they won't implement any action based on that change (it must be programmed).

For your specific question - it generally depends on which attribute we want to view. For "midpoint", use the `get_nodes_attr` function, with the "midpoint" parameter - from the [dendextend](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/) package.

```
# install.packages("dendextend")
library(dendextend)

dend <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(USArrests[1:5,])))
# Like: 
# dend <- USArrests[1:5,] %>% dist %>% hclust %>% as.dendrogram

# midpoint for all nodes
get_nodes_attr(dend, "midpoint")
```

And you get this:

```
[1] 1.25   NA 1.50 0.50   NA   NA 0.50   NA   NA
```

To also change an attribute, you can use the various assign functions from the package: `assign_values_to_leaves_nodePar`, `assign_values_to_leaves_edgePar`, `assign_values_to_nodes_nodePar`, `assign_values_to_branches_edgePar`, `remove_branches_edgePar`, `remove_nodes_nodePar`

If all you want is to change the labels, the following ability from the package would solve your question:

```
> labels(dend)
[1] "Arkansas"   "Arizona"    "California" "Alabama"    "Alaska"    
> labels(dend) <- 1:5
> labels(dend)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

For more details on the package, you can have a look [at its vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/vignettes/introduction.html).